# Mover un elemento con css solo dentro del elemento padre

Tags: javascript, html, css

Estoy armando un tipo de juego de practica en el que cada vez que se cada click en un boton este se mueve a otra posicion dada por cordenadas random dentro de un rango, pero se me sale de la caja. Que propiedad deberia usar para que se mantenga dentro?

```js
function getCordenada(min, max){
  let cordenada = Math.floor(Math.random()* (max-min +1)+min);
  return cordenada;
}
getCordenada(-400, 400);

function mover(){
  let cordenada1 = getCordenada(-100, 100);  
    let cordenada2 = getCordenada(-100, 100);  
document.getElementById("botonaso").style.left=cordenada1 + "px";
document.getElementById("botonaso").style.top=cordenada2 + "px";
}
```

```css
.caja{
  background-color:green;
  min-height: 505px;
  min-width: 505px;
}

.boton{
  height: 60px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position:relative;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
  <head>
    <title>Juego AIM</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Juego AIM1</h1>
    <div class="caja">
      <button id="botonaso" class="boton" onclick="mover()">Push me</button>
    </div>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que pasar siempre la posicion en positivo como ya mencionaron y tambien puedes contemplar el maximo y minimo dinamicamente.

```js
const juegoContainer = document.querySelector('#juego');
const juegoBtn = document.querySelector('#btn');

juegoBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
 let maxX = juegoContainer.offsetWidth - juegoBtn.offsetWidth;
  let maxY = juegoContainer.offsetHeight - juegoBtn.offsetHeight;
 let posX = Math.floor(Math.random() * maxX);
  let posY = Math.floor(Math.random() * maxY);
  juegoBtn.style.top = `${posY}px`;
  juegoBtn.style.left = `${posX}px`;
})
```

```css
#juego{
  background: red;
  margin: 30px auto;
  position: relative;
  width: calc(100% - 50px);
  height: 200px;
}

#btn{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: #fff;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="juego">
  <span id="btn"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pasa siempre un valor positivo.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        .caja{
            background-color:green;
            min-height: 505px;
            width: 100%;
        }

        .boton{
            height: 60px;
            border-radius: 30px;
            cursor: pointer;
            position:relative;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="programa.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Juego AIM1</h1>
    <div class="caja">
      <button id="botonaso" class="boton">Push me</button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Y evita siempre el onclick en el elemento html. El archivo programa.js contiene lo siguiente, de esa manera no se sale.

```
    window.onload = function() {
        document.getElementById("botonaso").addEventListener("click", mover);
    };

    function getCordenada(min, max){
        let cordenada = Math.floor(Math.random()* (max-min +1)+min);
        return cordenada;
    } 
    function mover(){
        let cordenada1 = getCordenada(0, 200);
        console.log("Valor coordenada 1: "+cordenada1);
        let cordenada2 = getCordenada(0, 200);
        console.log("Valor coordenada 2: "+cordenada2);
        document.getElementById("botonaso").style.left=cordenada1 + "px";
        document.getElementById("botonaso").style.top=cordenada2 + "px";
    }
```